# XML name space and stylesheet

Tags: xml

Can some one please explain me relation between namespaces defined in xml, xsd and xsl ( stylesheet)?

My XSL is not working if I use default namespace.

Namespace in I have used

in XSD

```
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.010.001.01" 
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
 targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.010.001.01">
```

in XML

```
<Document 
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.010.001.01 acmt010.xsd" 
xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.010.001.01" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
```

In XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsi="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.010.001.01" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.010.001.01 file:/C:/xml/working/testing/acmt.010.001.01.xsd" 
>
```

My XSL transformation is not working.

However if I change my namespace in xml to

```
<Document 
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.010.001.01 acmt010.xsd" 
xmlns:xsl="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.010.001.01" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
```

Then transformation is working but xml editior tool is giving warning "cvc-elt.1: The element declaration was not found for root element ".

can some help me with this?